# Javascript issue using API with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, api, mongoose

I am creating a simple AngularJS SPA and using API to connect to Mongoose. But I keep getting the following error when simply trying to add a new member, the member does actually add to mongoose but will not be seen on my webpage until I refresh. And when I press the Add Member button I get the following error in Google Chrome Dev Tools:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.addMember (app.js:195)

I have no idea how to get around it.  Here is my app.js

```
app.controller('MembersController', ['$scope','SimpleFactory',
    function ($scope,SimpleFactory) {

        SimpleFactory.getMembers()
        .success(function(members) {
        $scope.members = members;
        });

    $scope.addMember = function()
    {
        var member = {
            name: $scope.newMember.name,
            address: $scope.newMember.address,
            age : $scope.newMember.age,
            level : $scope.newMember.level,
            swimmer : $scope.newMember.swimmer,
            email : $scope.newMember.email,
            regdate : $scope.newMember.regdate,
                    }

          SimpleFactory.addMember(member)
          .success(function(added_member) 
          { 
             $scope.members.push(added_member);
             $scope.newMember = { }
          }       );
    }

    $scope.membNoInRange = function () 
    {
        return  $scope.memberNo && $scope.memberNo >=0 
                        && $scope.memberNo < $scope.members.length
    }
}])
```

Adding in my factory service:

```
app.factory('SimpleFactory', ['$http', function($http){

var members =  $http.get('/api/members') 

factory.getMembers = function () 
    {
        return members = $http.get('/api/members');
    }

   factory.getMember = function (index) {
        if (index >=0 && index < members.length ) {
           return  members = $http.get('/api/members/' + member_id )
       }
       return undefined
    }

    factory.addMember = function(member) {
         $http.post('/api/members',member)
    }
    factory.updateMember = function(index,member) {
         $http.put('/api/members/' + member_id, member)
    }

     return factory;
}])
```

Can anyone help, do I need to provide more information?

Comment: What is the result of `.success(function(added_member)`?Are you sure this is the raw body?

Comment: Hi Edward, could you explain a bit more, I'm only learning javasript as I go! Thanks. Do I need to provide more info, do I need to show my factory service?

Comment: Yes please, it looks like you haven't returned an http promise which is what .success is expecting. Can you paste the `SimpleFactory.addMember` function?

Comment: Thanks, just added it to my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions of the service are not returning a promise.

Try adding return before the $http...

```
factory.addMember = function(member) {
     return $http.post('/api/members', member)
}
factory.updateMember = function(index,member) {
     return $http.put('/api/members/' + member_id, member)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Edward, it fixed that problem for me!